# Is there a comprehensive list of Portuguese words ranked by frequency of use which is freely available online?

Tags: vocabulário, recursos-online

While studying Chinese I was presented to a a number of [lists](http://hanzidb.org/character-list/by-frequency) of most commonly employed characters, which is a truly invaluable resource for beginners and teachers approaching a foreign language.

Soon after I found out such lists exist for [a number of idioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_lists_by_frequency) (e.g. [English](https://www.wordfrequency.info/), [French](http://frequencylists.blogspot.com/2016/08/5000-french-sentences-sorted-from.html)), from which fascinating discussions regarding geographical and area-specific differences of vocabulary use.

However I cannot find the same (i.e. freely available online resource) for Portuguese language. 
Please, would anyone know here of some website containing such a database?

Comment: Most common in which context? You can extract such a list for most corpora in Portuguese. See e.g. [this list](https://www.linguateca.pt/acesso/contabilizacao.php#listaPosCETEMPUBLICO). For CETEMPúblico: https://www.linguateca.pt/acesso/tokens/formas.cetempublico.txt

Comment: @Artefacto Thanks for the link, it looks interesting. However, would you know of some unified, comprehensive list which is more user-friendly, and based on a large body of textual sources, such as the ones in the examples from other languages?

Comment: Linguateca gives access to several corpora, see https://www.linguateca.pt/acesso/info_freq_English.php . Also worth checking apparently is http://www2.lael.pucsp.br/corpora/ .

Comment: @stafusa This first link you provide looks more like it. Could you make it an answer? Now, I cannot seem to make the second linked tool work properly.

Comment: Done. And, now that I took a closer look at that second page, I also don't find it so useful for your purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Artefacto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/249) pointed out in a comment, Linguateca gives access to several corpora with the frequency information you're seeking. Check their [Rank and frequency in Portuguese](http://linguateca.pt/acesso/info_freq_English.php).